# How to debug the network disconnection?

Tags: networking, server

if UBUNTU server with working static network configuration is suddenly disconnected and not able to reach the Gateway. How can i debug? Can any one please help on this.

Comment: Assuming (because you did not tell us) that your NIC is `eth<digit>`, the command `egrep -n 'eth[[:digit:]]' /var/log/* 2>/dev/null ` will show where, in which of the system's log files, your NIC is mentioned. Read those log files.